# RedHat Kickstart

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, kickstart

I'm looking into creating a kickstart script to get a default build of a system.

However this system requires some in-house software which are currently on DVDs.

As this is my first `kickstart` installation of redhat, I haven't a clue where to start.
?
Do I need to `rpm-ify` (if you will) these DVDs? Do I bundle these in with the packages you found on a standard redhat `.iso`? e.g. `/media/iso/Server/big_list/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you normally install the software on the DVDs? If the machines are networked you can put whatever commands are required to download and install the software in the %post section of you kickstart file. I would put all of the required software on a web server on your network(tar archive or rpms) and get it with wget. From there you can do whatever you need to in the kick start file to do the install(rpm -i, ./install.sh, ./configure && make && make install).

You could also setup your own repository which would allow you to just list the rpm and would make updates easy if you can rpm-ify everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful links to get you started with kickstart installations:

- [Automating the Installation with Kickstart of RHEL6 installation Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-automating-installation.html)
- [kickstart section in the RHNSS deployment guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.4/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Getting_Started_Guide-Satellite_Operation_Guidance-Kickstart.html)

The second is specific to kickstart installations through a RHNSS (Satellite) server but the kickstart configuration can mostly be applied to regular kickstart installations as well.

I would recommend building RPM's for the software you need if only to allow easy updates later on.  But as @chuck wrote you can simply run the installation procedures you use today in a %post section.